# Drop Rows by Multiple Column Criteria in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that I'm trying to drop rows based on a criteria across select columns.  If the values in these select columns are zero, the rows should be dropped.  Here is an example.

```
import pandas as pd
t = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,0,0,2],'b':[1,2,0,0],'c':[1,2,3,4]})

  a b c
0 1 1 1 
1 0 2 2 
2 0 0 3 
3 2 0 4
```

I would like to try something like:

```
cols_of_interest = ['a','b'] #Drop rows if zero in all these columns
t = t[t[cols_of_interest]!=0]
```

This doesn't drop the rows, so I tried:

```
t = t.drop(t[t[cols_of_interest]==0].index)
```

And all rows are dropped.

What I would like to end up with is:

```
  a b c
0 1 1 1 
1 0 2 2 
3 2 0 4
```

Where the 3rd row (index 2) was dropped because it took on value 0 in BOTH the columns of interest, not just one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem here is that you first assigned the result of your boolean condition: `t = t[t[cols_of_interest]!=0]` which overwrites your original df and sets where the condition is not met with `NaN` values.

What you want to do is generate the boolean mask, then drop the `NaN` rows and pass `thresh=1` so that there must be at least a single non-`NaN` value in that row, we can then use `loc` and use the index of this to get the desired df:

```
In [124]:

cols_of_interest = ['a','b']
t.loc[t[t[cols_of_interest]!=0].dropna(thresh=1).index]
Out[124]:
   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  0  2  2
3  2  0  4
```

**EDIT**

As pointed out by @DSM you can achieve this simply by using `any` and passing `axis=1` to test the condition and use this to index into your df:

```
In [125]:

t[(t[cols_of_interest] != 0).any(axis=1)]
Out[125]:
   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  0  2  2
3  2  0  4
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply use `t[(t[cols_of_interest] != 0).any(axis=1)]` or something?

Comment: @DSM good point, I was literally fixing up the OP's attempt, will update

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know about the Boolean mask thing- I'll have to read about that further.  The second edit/answer also makes sense.

Comment: It's worth checking out the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html